# "Invalid template argument" error in Visual Studio but not GCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc

suppose you have the code

```
template <template<class> class BaseType>
class EST16
    : public BaseType<int>
{
public:
    EST16(double d) 
    {
    }
};

template <class T>
class SCEST
{
    T y;
};
typedef EST16<SCEST> EST16_SC;
class Child
    : public EST16_SC
{
public:
    Child()
        : EST16_SC(1.0)
    {
    }

};



class NotWorkingChild
    : public EST16<SCEST>
{
public:
    NotWorkingChild()
        : EST16<SCEST>(1.0)
    {
    }

};



TEST(TemplateTest, TestInstantiate)
{
    Child child;
    NotWorkingChild notWorkingChild; 
}
```

Child and NotWorkingChild differ only by the typedef. In GCC both compile, in Visual Studio the constructor of NotWorkingChild produces the following error:

```
2>..\..\..\src\itenav\test\SCKFErrorStateTest.cpp(43) : error C3200: 'SCEST<T>' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'BaseType', expected a class template
2>        with
2>        [
2>            T=int
2>        ]
```

Can you explain why this is the case? Is there a better portable solution than the typedef?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you written any code that actually instantiates and uses the template classes? By that I mean in, say, `main`. One thing that might be happening is that VCC tests the instantiation when seeing the `typedef`, while GCC doesn't bother until one of your child classes is actually used. If that's true, then you would get errors in GCC as well, as soon as you actually write code that uses one of the child class templates.

Comment: Yes, I did. The TEST macro creates a Google Test that actually gets called from main().

Comment: Sorry -- the `TEST` macro was just after my scrolling cutoff, so I missed it. I'm not 100% why this fails, but I've posted an alternative approach below that should be more portable across compilers. It is also more readable, in my humble opinion :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message is because `NotWorkingChild` derives (indirectly) from `SCEST<int>`, which makes `SCEST` inside the scope of `NotWorkingChild` refer to the class `SCEST<int>`, instead of the template. MSVC is correct to reject this, and GCC4.5 should reject this too (GCC4.5 has more correct injected class name lookup).

Here is a solution that might work for both compilers

```
class NotWorkingChild
    : public EST16<SCEST>
{
public:
    NotWorkingChild()
        : EST16< ::SCEST >(1.0)
    {
    }

};
```

Notice that we use the scope resolution operator and need to put a space before `::` (the token `<:` would otherwise be taken as a digraph).

---

**Breaking News**: C++0x will make the above work even if you do `EST16<SCEST>`. The reason is, that it says that if the injected class name is passed to a template template parameter, the injected class name is treated as a template, instead of as a type. Therefor, for C++0x, GCC would be the compiler doing it correctly.

Comment: Seems VS "14" CTP still requires the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 2):

It compiles on VS if you change the initialiser to just refer to the template class name, EST16. I.e.:

```
class NotWorkingChild : public EST16<SCEST>
{
public:
    NotWorkingChild()
        : EST16(1.0)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: that's correct, but I am looking for a portable solution and this does not compile with GCC :-(