# Are template arguments required everywhere when mentioning a template base class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, subclassing, c++builder-xe

Here's a simple template;

```
template <class T>
class tt {
    private:
        T  x;
    public:
        tt() {x=0;};
        Add(T p) {x += p;};
};
```

... and then a subclass of it;

```
class cc : public tt<int> {

    public:
        cc() : tt() {};

};
```

This compiles fine in VC, but not in C++ Builder (XE) where it gives a E2102 error. The C++ Builder compiler needs the following syntax on the constructor of the cc class to compile;

```
cc() : tt<int>() {};
```

In fact, the C++ Builder compiler needs the template parameters repeated every time the tt template are mentioned within the cc class.

Does the standard C++ specification specify the need for constantly repeating the template parameters or is the C++ Builder compiler wrong?

Comment: `tt` is a template. `tt<int>` is a type. You can only derive from types.

Comment: you can avoid the repeatetions by using typedef

Comment: @KerrekSB, doesn't `tt` refer to the injected class name from `tt<int>`?

Comment: Yes, typedef's is the plan if I have to repeat the template params. To me it seems kind of strange that the definitions needs repetitions, the type given in "**class cc : public tt<int>**" should be enough since I cannot use other params later.

Comment: @avakar: I think that's only true for the class template itself; i.e. if you say `template <typename T> class Foo;`, then `Foo` refers to the current instance. I'm not 100% sure though. Let's wait for an authoritative answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

C++ Builder is wrong here. The reason why you should be able to use the ancestor's name in the constructor's member initializer list has to do with the concept of *injected class name*.

When you define a class, the compiler inserts the name of the class into that class and makes it refer to itself. This injected name is what allows you to use the name of the class without template arguments inside the class.

```
template <class T>
struct tt {
    // The compiler behaves as if there was the following.
    // typedef tt<T> tt;
};
```

This injected name is what gets looked up when you use the name `tt` in the member initializer list.

(For the record, clang accepts the snippet without the template argument.)

**Bonus:** had you defined `cc` as a class template with the template parameter `T` and the ancestor was dependent on `T`, the name `tt` would not be found in the context of `cc`'s constructor's member initializer list.

```
template <class T>
class cc : tt<T> {
    cc()
        : tt<T>() /* You must use <T> here. */
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for the correct detailed answer. Another interesting consequence of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5315134/34509

Comment: So g++ is wrong for not injecting the name into the child class?  g++ 4.2 and 4.4 certainly don't pick up the injected name. Is there a reference that injected names are inherited?

Comment: @MarkB, technically, names from a base don't get injected into a child class; instead the lookup algorithm is designed to search base classes for a name if that name cannot be found in the child. g++ is wrong in not finding the injected name of the child during lookup.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Note; VC compiles even if cc is defined as a template (as in Your example but without the <T> in the construtor), so CBuilder, VC and gcc all fails (in different ways) to do this "correctly"...

Comment: @FrankE, yes, VC is known for performing certain lookups at the point of instantiation instead of at the point of definition of the template. Once `cc<T>` gets instantiated to `cc<int>`, the base class becomes `tt<int>` and the lookup for `tt` succeeds.

Comment: Regarding the bonus section, you don't *have to* use `tt<T>` there. You can simply use `cc::tt` instead to access the parent's injected name, which is a big deal if you have multiple template parameters and their names aren't so short.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the repetitions by using typedef:

```
typedef tt<int> tti;
```

...

```
class cc : public tti {

    public:
        cc() : tti() {};

};
```

Comment: That's just a workaround. It doesn't really answer the question of what the standard specifies, though.

Comment: I know (and that's my plan if I have to). But why should the tt params need repetition at all ?