# List of prime factors at compile-time: specialization error

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, specialization

Consider the following code (link to [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9v4uCx)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// List of factors
template<std::intmax_t ... Misc> 
struct factors { };

// Declaration
template<std::intmax_t ... Misc> 
struct factorization;

// Initial specialization
template<std::intmax_t Value> 
struct factorization<Value>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Value % 2 == 0,
            typename factorization<Value / 2, 2, 2>::type,
            typename factorization<Value / 2, 2 + 1>::type>::type type;
};

// Initial specialization when the value is not divisible by 2
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor> 
struct factorization<Value, Divisor>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Value % Divisor == 0,
            typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor, Divisor>::type,
            typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor + 1>::type>::type type;
};

// Specialization after the first recusion step
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t Prime> 
struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Value % Divisor == 0,
            typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor, Divisor>::type,
            typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor + 1>::type>::type type;
};

// Recursion specialization
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t Prime, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<Value % Divisor == 0 && Divisor != Prime,
            typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor, Divisor, Prime,
                    Primes...>::type,
            typename factorization<
                    Value % Divisor == 0 ? Value / Divisor : Value,
                    Divisor + (Value % Divisor != 0), Prime, Primes...>::type>::type type;
};

// Last recursion step
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization<Value, Value, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename factorization<1, Value, Value, Primes...>::type type;
};

// Finalize
template<std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization<1, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef factors<Primes...> type;
};

// Main
int main() {
    typename factorization<18>::type x;
    return 0;
}
```

This code should list the prime factors of a number without repetition:
for example, `factorization<18>::type` should be equal to `factors<2, 3>`

But it fails with the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct factorization<4ll, 2ll, 2ll>’:
prog.cpp:36:79:   required from ‘struct factorization<9ll, 2ll, 2ll>’
prog.cpp:18:67:   required from ‘struct factorization<18ll>’
prog.cpp:67:28:   required from here
prog.cpp:36:79: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct factorization<2ll, 2ll, 2ll>’
             typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor + 1>::type>::type type;
                                                                               ^
prog.cpp:32:8: error: candidates are: struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime>
 struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime>
        ^
prog.cpp:41:8: error:                 struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime, Primes ...>
 struct factorization<Value, Divisor, Prime, Primes...>
        ^
prog.cpp:53:8: error:                 struct factorization<Value, Value, Primes ...>
 struct factorization<Value, Value, Primes...>
        ^
prog.cpp:36:79: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct factorization<2ll, 2ll, 2ll>’
             typename factorization<Value / Divisor, Divisor + 1>::type>::type type;
                                                                               ^
prog.cpp:10:8: error: declaration of ‘struct factorization<2ll, 2ll, 2ll>’
 struct factorization;
        ^
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:67:30: error: invalid combination of multiple type-specifiers
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                              ^
prog.cpp:67:36: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                                    ^
prog.cpp:67:35: warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                                   ^

Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:67:30: error: ‘type’ in ‘struct factorization<18ll>’ does not name a type
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                              ^
prog.cpp:67:36: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                                    ^
prog.cpp:67:35: warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]
  typename factorization<18>::type x;
                                   ^
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you ever hear of newlines?

Comment: It might help us if you paste the full template error message up on pastebin or something. It's hard to debug expansions and specializations without a full stack trace.

Comment: BTW there's no reason to make the entrypoint a specialization of the implementation -- that just makes it possible for the user to accidentally supply extra arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specialization (as far as I can tell) that matches `factorization<18>`, unless you're omitting some code. Every one of your specializations seems to assume at least two parameters are being passed into factorization.

From the comments you've added, it seems you're assuming that the specialization labelled "initial specialization" will catch the case where you just pass in a single number. This isn't true. Try running `factorization<18, 2>` to see that in action. If this is indeed what you want, then either omit the 2 in your specialization and keep the body the same, or add one final specialization that simply matches on a single number and sets `type` to `typename factorization<N, 2>::type`.

Comment: Well now it seems like you're getting some ambiguous issues. Make sure your expansions are mutually exclusive so that at any given time only one is legal.

Comment: I do not understand why this is ambiguous. It may be linked to the expansion pack, but I do not understand why...

Comment: Think about what happens when your pack is empty. The compiler is listing a few versions of `factorization` that it could expand, some of which are only valid with an empty pack. You need to take those cases into consideration when defining template specializations.

Comment: Class variadic templates do not have the same rule as function variadic templates ? Because for function, a variadic template is always considered as less specialized...

Comment: That is not true. See section 14.5.6 (partial ordering of function templates.) Then see section 14.5.2 (partial ordering of class templates). The last example in 14.5.6 is what you want to look at. Your code is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working version.  Note that using `std::conditional` is a bad idea, because both branches still have to be expanded.  Specialization works much better.

```
// List of factors
template<std::intmax_t...> 
struct factors { };

// Declaration
template<bool no_remainder, std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization_remove_repeated;
template<bool no_remainder, std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization_check;

// wraps the remainder check to reduce code duplication
template<template<bool, std::intmax_t ...> class T, std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ...Primes> 
struct factorization_advance
{
    typedef typename T<(Value % Divisor) == 0, Value, Divisor, Primes...>::type type;
};

// end case
template<template<bool, std::intmax_t ...> class T, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization_advance<T, 1, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef factors<Primes...> type;
};

// No more repeats of Divisor, move to Divisor+1
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization_remove_repeated<false, Value, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename factorization_advance<factorization_check, Value, Divisor + 1, Primes...>::type type;
};

// removed a repeat of Divisor, continue doing so, without adding to primes list
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes>
struct factorization_remove_repeated<true, Value, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename factorization_advance<::factorization_remove_repeated, Value / Divisor, Divisor, Primes...>::type type;
};

// found that Divisor isn't a factor, move to Divisor+1
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes> 
struct factorization_check<false, Value, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename factorization_advance<::factorization_check, Value, Divisor + 1, Primes...>::type type;
};

// Found first occurrence of a factor, add to primes list, remove repeats
template<std::intmax_t Value, std::intmax_t Divisor, std::intmax_t ... Primes>
struct factorization_check<true, Value, Divisor, Primes...>
{
    typedef typename factorization_advance<factorization_remove_repeated, Value / Divisor, Divisor, Primes..., Divisor>::type type;
};

// Convenience wrapper
template<std::intmax_t Value> 
struct factorization
{
    typedef typename factorization_advance<factorization_check, Value, 2>::type type;
};
```

- Demo: http://rextester.com/NPGBU58803
- Earlier version that also works but less maintainable IMO: http://ideone.com/Ia9hnd

Comment: I tried compiling this code with MSVC and ran into problems. (Error: `c3200` and `c2955`) I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287778/how-do-i-use-the-class-name-inside-the-class-itself-as-a-template-argument). You need to change `factorization_advance<factorization_check,...` into `factorization_advance<::factorization_check,...` and `factorization_advance<factorization_remove_repeated,...` into `factorization_advance<::factorization_remove_repeated,...`!

Comment: @jan.sende: Ahh, the injected-class-name.  Newer versions of the compilers are more particular, I'll update.

Comment: Sorry! I only wrote this comment to help others trying out your code. But reading it now, it actually sounds more like a suggestion.... But thanks for editing it!