# CRTP with Template Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, template-templates

The following code doesn't compile...

```
namespace {
    template<typename T, template<typename> class D>
    struct Base {
        Base(const T& _t) : t(_t) { }
        T t;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Derived : Base<T, Derived> {
        Derived(const T& _t) : Base<T, Derived>(_t) { }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Derived<int> d(1);
    return 0;
}
```

There is a compilation error on the line - `Derived(const T& _t) : Base<T, Derived>(_t) { }`

> Error C3200   '`anonymous-namespace'::Derived': invalid template
>   argument for template parameter 'D', expected a class template

This works if I provide any other class that has template argument instead of Derived itself

```
template<typename T>
struct Other {

};
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T, Other> {
    Derived(const T& _t) : Base<T, Other>(_t) { }
};
```

Comment: The reason is that `D` of `Base` expects a template. Inside `Derived<int>` the name `Derived` is the injected instance of `Derived` (namely `Derived<int>` in your case) which is not a template but a concrete type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the class-name inside the class itself as a template argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287778/how-do-i-use-the-class-name-inside-the-class-itself-as-a-template-argument)

Answer (score 18):

Tl;dr: the most portable and least extensive way to get around that problem seems to be using the qualified name `::Derived` in your example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T, Derived>
{
  Derived(const T& _t) : Base<T, ::Derived>(_t) { }
};
```

#### Why?

The Problem is compiler non-conformance to C++11.

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). **The injected class-name can be used as a template-name** or a type-name. **When it is used** with a template-argument-list, **as a template-argument for a template template-parameter**, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-typespecifier of a friend class template declaration, **it refers to the class template itself.**

Thus your code should compile but unfortunately, all compilers I tested (clang 3.7, Visual Studio 2015 and g++5.3) refuse to do it.

Afaik, you should be able to denote the template in various ways, inside the `Derived` definition:

- Using the injected name directly `Derived`
- Qualified name of the class template `::Derived`
- Using the injected class name, designating it as a template name `Derived<T>::template Derived`
- Using a qualified name, again designating it as a template name `::template Derived`

The compilation status of those compilers regarding those four options is as follows (using the anonymus namespace; where `+` = successful compilation):

```
+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
|           Method             | MSVS2015 | g++ 5.3 | clang 3.7 |
+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Derived                      |    -     |    -    |     -     |
| ::Derived                    |    +     |    +    |     +     |
| Derived<T>::template Derived |    -     |    -    |     +     |
| ::template Derived           |    +     |    -    |     +     |
+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

When giving the namespace the name `X`, the picture changes a little (namely `g++` now accepts `X::template Derived` whereas it rejected `::template Derived`):

```
+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
|            Method               | MSVS2015 | g++ 5.3 | clang 3.7 |
+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Derived                         |    -     |    -    |     -     |
| X::Derived                      |    +     |    +    |     +     |
| X::Derived<T>::template Derived |    -     |    -    |     +     |
| X::template Derived             |    +     |    +    |     +     |
+---------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 15):

In a class template, the injected-class-name (`Derived` in your example) can be both a type name and a template name. The standard specifies that it should be considered to name  the template when used as an argument to a template template parameter (so your code should work), but unfortunately some compilers haven't yet implemented this.

One workaround is to use a qualified name, so that you don't use the injected-class-name but directly name the template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T, Derived> {
    Derived(const T& _t) : Base<T, ::Derived>(_t) { }
};
```

Comment: "some compilers" which?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You think it should always be a *template-name* and can't be used as a *type-name*?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Correct. `The point of declaration for an injected-class-name (Clause 9) is immediately following the opening brace
of the class definition.`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Oh, right, in the base-specifier. You are right - everyone thinks that one is a *template-name*. Fixed.

Comment: Denoting the class template using the injected name through `Derived::template Derived` compiles using clang 3.7 but is rejected by MSVC 2015 as well as g++5.3.

Comment: @Pixelchemist MSVC is weird; it rejects in mem-initializers but not elsewhere. Going to remove it anyway, no point having a workaround that only partially works.